# Using ffprobe to check if file is audio or video only

Tags: video, ffmpeg, ffprobe

Is there an ffprobe command I can run to see if an mov file that I have is audio-only or contains video as well? I have various mov files, some of which are audio dubs and some of which are full videos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can output stream information in JSON or XML:

`ffprobe -show_streams -print_format json input.mov`

You'll get an array of streams with a `codec_type` attribute with values like `audio`, `video` etc.

Answer (score 26):

## To output the `codec_type`

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries stream=codec_type -of default=nw=1 input.foo
```

Example result:

```
codec_type=video
codec_type=audio
```

If you have multiple audio or video streams the output will show multiple video or audio entries.

---

## Same as above but output just the values

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries stream=codec_type -of default=nw=1=nk=1 input.foo
```

or:

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries stream=codec_type -of csv=p=0 input.foo
```

Example result:

```
video
audio
```

---

## To include the stream index

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries stream=index,codec_type -of csv=p=0 input.foo
```

Example result:

```
0,video
1,audio
```

In this example the video is the first stream and the audio is the second stream which is the norm but not always the case.

---

## Output nothing if there is no audio

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams a -show_entries stream=codec_type -of csv=p=0 input.foo
```

Example result for input with audio:

```
audio
```

If the input does **not** have audio then there will be no output (null output) which could be useful for scripted usage.

---

## JSON output example

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries stream=codec_type -of json input.mkv
```

Example result:

```
{
    "programs": [

    ],
    "streams": [
        {
            "codec_type": "video"
        },
        {
            "codec_type": "audio"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

## Other output formats

If you want different output formatting (ini, flat, compact, csv, xml) see [FFprobe Documentation: Writers](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html#Writers).

Answer (score 0):

To find out programmatically if a video file has audio, use `avformat_open_input()` as shown here below - if `audio_index` is bigger or equal to zero, then the video file has audio.

```
if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, filename, nullptr, nullptr) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open video file!\n");
    return -1;
}

if (avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, nullptr) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't find stream information!\n");
    return -1;
}

av_dump_format(pFormatCtx, 0, videoState->filename, 0);

for (i = 0; i < pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++) {

    if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO && video_index < 0)
        video_index = i;

    if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO && audio_index < 0)
        audio_index = i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using ffprobe with json, like this:

```
ffmpeg -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams {FILENAME}
```

search for index [duration] on streams index. If is numeric && is > 0, them, i think that this is a VIDEO.

The problem on searching only for the word "video" is that, a JPG has a "video" stream, so this isn't a bad idea. For me, i use search for the duration value... Works very well!

Answer (score -2):

One quick way to do this is to check if the word 'Video' is in the output. Here's an example:

```
>>> cmd = shlex.split('%s -i %s' % (FFPROBE, video_path))
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> output = p.communicate()[1]
>>> 'Video' in output
True
```

I tried this for a few different files and it seemed to work on the ones I tried, though I'm sure there's a much better solution.

Comment: Far from ideal, your file may contain `video` in the filename for eg.