# Sorting video files based on whether they contain sound or not

Tags: c#, python, ffprobe

I have never done any programming until now, so I am open to any language. How do I start on a script to sort videos into those with sound and those without sound? I have hundreds of short mp4/avi clips that are randomly named. Is it possible to write a piece of code that automatically sorts them based on whether they have audio?

Can anyone write me the script? I would be eternally grateful. If not, can anyone point me to some easy to understand tutorials? I was told to use ffprobe and a script but I have no idea how to start.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ffprobe to check audio-only files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278277/using-ffprobe-to-check-audio-only-files)

Comment: Off topic on the site due to "Can anyone write me the script?" - it is not what this site is about. If you can at least make a first attempt and explain where stuck, the question might be rescued. You may want to try some very basic language tutorials, such as https://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can run directly at the command line,

```
for %i in (*.mp4 *.avi) do ffmpeg -i "%i" -v 0 -map a -t 0.1 -f null - && move "%i" with-audio || move "%i" no-audio
```

where `with-audio` and `no-audio` are sub-folders you created in the location where you ran the command. You can, of course, replace these with absolute paths to a central set of folders. If using within a batch file, replace `%i` with `%%i`

Basic logic is that the given ffmpeg command will report success if a given file has audio and failure otherwise. In the former case, the command after the `&&` gets executed, In the latter, the command after the `||` gets executed.

Comment: Thanks you very much! i was really struggling on how to start! thanks again