# Python get list of streams from video (audio/video)

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a video file and I want to get the list of streams from it. I can see the needed result by for example executing a simple `ffprobe video.mp4:

```
....
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661) ......
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), ......
....
```

But I need to use python and code that will work both on Windows and Ubuntu, **without executing an external process**.

My real goal is to check whether there is ANY audio stream within the video (a simple yes/no would suffice), but I think getting extra information can be helpful for my problem, so I'm asking about the entire streams

EDIT: Clarifying that I need to avoid executing some external process, but looking for some python code/library to do it within the process.

Comment: refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278277/using-ffprobe-to-check-audio-only-files)

Comment: I saw it, but I need to do it from python

Answer (score 6):

```
import os
import json
import subprocess
file_path = os.listdir("path to your videos folder")
audio_flag = False

for file in file_path:
    ffprobe_cmd = "ffprobe -hide_banner -show_streams -print_format json "+file
    process = subprocess.Popen(ffprobe_cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    output = json.loads(process.communicate()[0])

for stream in output["streams"]:
    if(stream['codec_type'] == 'audio'):
        audio_flag = True
        break;
if(audio_flag):
    print("audio present in the file")
else:
    print("audio not present in the file")

# loop through the output streams for more detailed output 
for stream in output["streams"]:
    for k,v in stream.items():
        print(k, ":", v)
```

Note: Make sure that your **videos folder path** consist of only valid video files as i didn't include any file validation in the above code snippet. Also, I have tested this code for a video file that contains one video stream and one audio stream.