# FFMPEG -- Error when trying to concat multiple files with and without audio

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

Ok so thanks to a fellow user I have the following FFMPEG command that concats 4 videos together. Now if I use this command with 4 video files that all have audio everything works! However, if 1 or more of the videos do not have sound I get a "matches no streams" error.

Can someone spot whats wrong here please?

Video Input 1 - No Audio so adding the anullsrc
Video 2 - Has Audio
Video 3 - No Audio
Video 4 - Has Audio

```
ffmpeg -i noSound1.mp4 -i story1.mp4 -i noSound2.mp4 -i story2.mp4 -t 0.1 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo -filter_complex 
"[0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v0]; 
 [1:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v1]; 
 [2:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v2]; 
 [3:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v3]; 
 [0:a]aformat=sample_rates=48000:channel_layouts=stereo[a0]; 
 [1:a]aformat=sample_rates=48000:channel_layouts=stereo[a1]; 
 [2:a]aformat=sample_rates=48000:channel_layouts=stereo[a2]; 
 [3:a]aformat=sample_rates=48000:channel_layouts=stereo[a3]; 
 [v0][a0][v1][a1][v2][a2][v3][a3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=1[v][a]" 
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart testOutput.mp4
```

Here is the error:

```
Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description [0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v0];  [1:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v1];  [2:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v2];  [3:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v3];  [0:a]aformat=sample_rates=48000:channel_layouts=stereo[a0];  [1:a]aformat=sample_rates=48000:channel_layouts=stereo[a1];  [2:a]aformat=sample_rates=48000:channel_layouts=stereo[a2];  [3:a]aformat=sample_rates=48000:channel_layouts=stereo[a3];  [v0][a0][v1][a1][v2][a2][v3][a3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=1[v][a] matches no streams.
```

Now a slightly separate question. If I have N input videos where i do not know if they have sound or not, is there a way I can have a loop that does the above without having massive amounts of command lines?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone spot whats wrong here please?

In your command you are attempting to feed the audio from `noSound1.mp4` (`[0:a]`) and `noSound2.mp4` (`[2:a]`) to aformat, but these inputs have no audio.

All inputs must either have audio or no audio: you can't mix them. So that's what anullsrc (the silent audio generator) is for. It will make dummy/silent/filler audio for the inputs without audio. For the inputs without audio you need to feed anullsrc (`[4]` or `[4:a]` in your example) to concat:

```
ffmpeg -i noSound1.mp4 -i story1.mp4 -i noSound2.mp4 -i story2.mp4 -t 0.1 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo -filter_complex 
"[0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v0]; 
 [1:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v1]; 
 [2:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v2]; 
 [3:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v3]; 
 [1:a]aformat=sample_rates=48000:channel_layouts=stereo[a1]; 
 [3:a]aformat=sample_rates=48000:channel_layouts=stereo[a3]; 
 [v0][4][v1][a1][v2][4][v3][a3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=1[v][a]" 
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart testOutput.mp4
```

To understand the `[0:a]` syntax see [FFMPEG mux video and audio (from another video) - mapping issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12943003/) and [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map).

> Now a slightly separate question. If I have N input videos where i do not know if they have sound or not, is there a way I can have a loop that does the above without having massive amounts of command lines?

No, but you can use `ffprobe` to determine if an input has audio or not which should be helpful in scripting a solution. See [Using `ffprobe` to check audio-only files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32289198/).

Comment: thank you for the response. Incredibly helpful. Now it may be dumb but I thought the point of anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo was to ensure there was always audio (and if not it adds it)?

Comment: @Philban `-f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo` just acts as another input. There is no automatic "if there is no audio then add it" feature when using concat filter, so you have to manually tell concat which inputs to refer to.

Comment: Sorry! I thought I had replied here. Thanks for the help again! Got everything sorted....for now ;)