# ffmpeg 4.3 multipart trim issue

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, mp4, trim

I am trying to trim multiparts from single video using ffmpeg 4.3

here is the command i used

```
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]trim=start=4:end=22,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
 [0:a]atrim=start=4:end=22,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0]; \
 [0:v]trim=start=26:end=100,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
 [0:a]atrim=start=26:end=100,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1]; \
 [v0][a0][v1][a1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4`
```

Getting this error in FFMPEG 4.3 latest

```
[mpeg4 @ 0x2b14e80] Invalid pixel aspect ratio 3875/3864, limit is 255/255 reducing
```

please help if anyone have solution for ffmpeg 4.3

here is the log for the above command , please check

```
    ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23)
  configuration: --enable-openssl
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isom
  Duration: 00:09:00.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 218 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 322x400 [SAR 3875:3864 DAR 155:192], 168 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 47 kb/s (default)
File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> trim
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> trim
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> atrim
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> atrim
  concat:out:v0 -> Stream #0:0 (mpeg4)
  concat:out:a0 -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpeg4 @ 0x25c4880] Invalid pixel aspect ratio 3875/3864, limit is 255/255 reducing
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isom
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 322x400 [SAR 255:254 DAR 8211:10160], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, SAR 3875:3864 DAR 155:192, 24 fps, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 mpeg4
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 aac
frame= 2208 fps=566 q=16.1 Lsize=    3970kB time=00:01:32.01 bitrate= 353.5kbits/s speed=23.6x    
video:2480kB audio:1442kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.204748%
[aac @ 0x25d9180] Qavg: 215.673
```

Comment: @llogan video never shows when this error occurs , mp4 file only shows audio , i have tried scaling also but didn't worked, this happening only in ffmpeg 4.3 and i cant switch to any other ffmpeg version , please help me out , i am stuck in this past 1 week :(

Comment: @llogan company has installed latest 4.3 and cant upgrade to more currently , please help me something

Comment: @llogan has configuration: --enable-openssl 
only have this config , is this the issue , please tell me which config needs to be enabled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## MPEG-4 Part 2 video is old

Your `ffmpeg` was not compiled to include support for any H.264 encoders, so it is forced use the encoder named *mpeg4* which outputs the old format MPEG-4 Part 2 video. This is a legacy format which was common before H.264.

Your device/player/app/browser probably doesn't support MPEG-4 Part 2 video.

Output H.264 instead.

## Solutions

- [Download an already compiled `ffmpeg`](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) that has what you need. Put it in your `PATH` (see [FAQ](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/faq/)), or provide the full path to the new `ffmpeg` in your script.
- Or re-compile `ffmpeg` with `--enable-gpl --enable-libx264`. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Compile & Install FFmpeg on CentOS/RHEL/Red Hat](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos).